# What is the fitted TFN model for this ARIMA (1,0,1)?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

This is the ARIMA model:

Regression with ARIMA(1,0,1) errors

Coefficients:

```
     ar1     ma1  intercept     GFT    GFT1    GFT2

  0.8294  0.3693  -103.7843  0.0754  0.0583  0.0077
```

sigma^2 estimated as: 5294

P.S. GFT, GFT1, GFT2 are 3 lags

Comment: What does *TFN model* mean?

Comment: TFN = Transfer function noise model, but it is built using auto.arima function in R

Comment: STA457? Yeah I am confused about the same thing did you figure it out? But the good news is that I have the same output as you